# Setting two scalar variables in one SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do this:

```
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;

SET @a,@b = (SELECT StartNum,EndNum FROM Users Where UserId = '1223')

PRINT @a
PRINT @b
```

But this is invalid syntax. How do I set multiple scalar variables in one select statement? I can do:

```
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;

SET @a = (SELECT StartNum FROM Users Where UserId = '1223')
SET @b = (SELECT EndNum FROM Users Where UserId = '1223')

PRINT @a
PRINT @b
```

But this will take twice as long. What is the fastest way?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a int;
DECLARE @b int;

SELECT @a = StartNum, @b = EndNum 
FROM Users 
WHERE UserId = '1223'
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I have a trouble working out the syntax of SQL. There are lots of keywords and structures that can be used in various unexpected ways.

Comment: @aF. Sorry! I got distracted and forgot to check back when the 12 minute accept limit was up.

Answer (score 15):

Do it like this:

```
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;

SELECT @a=StartNum,@b=EndNum FROM Users Where UserId = '1223'

PRINT @a
PRINT @b
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing this in a stored procedure and don't want the result of the select in an output resultset you will need to use the word INTO.

```
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;

SELECT StartNum, EndNum 
FROM Users 
Where UserId = '1223'
INTO @a, @b;
```

It also can be used like this:

```
SELECT StartNum, EndNum 
INTO @a, @b
FROM Users 
Where UserId = '1223';
```

Comment: I tried both of the ways described here on a SQL Server DB, and neither worked. Just a warning to anyone trying it this way.

Comment: @EthanConner It's been a long time since I posted this but it used to work, storing the values in the variables to be used in later part of stored procedure without pushing them to the output, did you get any specific error?

Comment: "Invalid syntax near 'into'" or something to that effect. SQL Server wouldn't let me do that format, but the "select @a = column_a" format worked fine