# SQL query error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." Output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that is being used in a C# controller class to return search query results:

```
SELECT @Output = (SELECT Name, Id
                  FROM [dbo].[Users]    
                  WHERE Name = 'Robert');
```

However, when I run this query, I get the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I know that simply removing one of the column names will fix the issue, but I want to be able to return the `Name` and `ID` for each searched user.

Is there a way to change my query so that I can return the desired columns and still keep my `@Output` parameter in the query? Any recommendations would be much appreciated

Comment: Change your select as `SELECT TOP Name From `

Comment: You can create [User defined types](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1628/sql-server-user-defined-data-types-rules-and-defaults/) but I don't think this would be a recommended solution.

Comment: Do you have two users named `Robert`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting two scalar variables in one SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127775/setting-two-scalar-variables-in-one-select-statement)

Comment: So, say `Name` is `varchar(20)` and `Id` is `int`. What data type are you *sensibly* going to use for `@Output` that can contain that pair of types? Also, you seem to *already know the `Name`*, so why do you need to retrieve it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to concatenate them:

```
SELECT @Output = (SELECT Name + '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), Id)
                  FROM [dbo].[Users]    
                  WHERE Name = 'Robert'
                 );
```

Another alternative is to use two variables, because you want two items:

```
SELECT @Name = Name, @Id = Id
FROM [dbo].[Users]    
WHERE Name = 'Robert';
```

Given that you know that the name is `'Robert'`, I don't see why that is useful.  You can do:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(255);

SET @Name = 'Robert';

SELECT @Id = Id
FROM [dbo].[Users]    
WHERE Name = @Name;
```

Comment: The first answer you provided will probably work best for me with my current query, thank you. Is there a way to print the output in SQL in a JSON string? Can you provide an example @Gordon Linoff?

Comment: @SamRR_75 . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, you can declare @output as table, and insert the values when condition is true.

```
  Declare @output table ([name] varchar(50), ID int) 

  insert into @output([name], id)     select 'abc', 1 

  select * from @output
```

Output: This is just sample data

```
 name   ID
 abc    1
```